# Binding hours and min and sec of timespan seperatly to model asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core

I have to get hours and min and sec in a form and use 3 input for that

```
@model LearnWebsite.Dtos.Course.CourseDTO

<div class="form-group ">
   <label class="" asp-for="Duration"></label>
   <div class="flex-container text-center mr-5">
     <input class="form-control" asp-for="Duration.Hours"/>
     <input class="form-control" asp-for="Duration.Minutes"/>
     <input class="form-control" asp-for="Duration.Seconds"/>
   </div>
</div>
```

Model have a property like this

public TimeSpan Duration { get; set; }

And Controller is like this

```
[HttpPost]
[AutoValidateAntiforgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateAsync(CourseDTO dTO)
{
}
```

But Duration property don't bind properly

[image: Duration Houre Min and Sec is 0]

Comment: I think it's because TimeSpan Hours and Minutes and Seconds property are readonly and can not set directly.                                                                                              dTO.Duration += TimeSpan.FromHours(Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["Duration.Hours"]));     This work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use the following methods to get the TimeSpan value.

1. Using JQuery

   In the View Page, add a hidden field:

   ```
    <div class="form-group ">
        <label class="" asp-for="Duration"></label>
        <div class="flex-container text-center mr-5">
            <input class="form-control" asp-for="Duration" type="hidden"/>
            <input class="form-control Durationhours" asp-for="Duration.Hours" />
            <input class="form-control Durationminutes" asp-for="Duration.Minutes" />
            <input class="form-control Durationseconds" asp-for="Duration.Seconds" />
        </div>
    </div>
   ```

   Then, use the following JQuery script: after user enter value, store the value in the hidden field

   ```
    @section Scripts {
        @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}

        <script>
            $(function () {

                $(".Durationhours, .Durationminutes, .Durationseconds").change(function () {
                    var hrs = $(".Durationhours").val() || 0;
                    var min = $(".Durationminutes").val() || 0;
                    var sec = $(".Durationseconds").val() || 0; 
                    $("#Duration").val(hrs + ":" + min + ":" + sec);
                });

            });
        </script>
    }
   ```

   Then, the result as below:

   [image]
2. In the controller, get the timespan via the `Request.Form()` method.

   In the controller, the code as below:

   ```
    [HttpPost]
    [AutoValidateAntiforgeryToken]
    public IActionResult CreateCourse(CourseDTO dTO)
    {
        dTO.Duration += TimeSpan.FromHours(Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["Duration.Hours"]));
        dTO.Duration += TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["Duration.Minutes"]));
        dTO.Duration += TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["Duration.Seconds"]));

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

        }
        return View();
    }
   ```

   the result like this:

   [image]
3. Using Custom ModelBinder

   Create a CourseDTOModelBinder:

   ```
    public class CourseDTOModelBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            if (bindingContext == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));

            var name = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("CourseName").FirstValue;
            if (name.Length == 0)
                return Task.CompletedTask;

            var hrs = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("Duration.Hours").FirstValue;
            var min = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("Duration.Minutes").FirstValue;
            var sec = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("Duration.Seconds").FirstValue;

            var result = new CourseDTO
            {
                CourseName = name,
                Duration = TimeSpan.FromHours(Convert.ToInt32(hrs)) + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Convert.ToInt32(min)) + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Convert.ToInt32(sec)) 
            };
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(result); 

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
   ```

   Then, apply the CourseDTOModelBinder attribute on the model and action method:

   ```
    [ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(CourseDTOModelBinder))]
    public class CourseDTO
    {
        public string CourseName { get; set; } 
        public TimeSpan Duration { get; set; }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [AutoValidateAntiforgeryToken]
    public IActionResult CreateCourse([ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(CourseDTOModelBinder))] CourseDTO dTO)
    {  
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

        }
        return View();
    }
   ```

   The result as below:

   [image]